# На пол пути свернуть в выполнение другого фала по окончанию вернуться в первый на то же место. Как это сделать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

maincalc.py

```
# калькулятор 1.6
import math
print("Здравствуйте, это калькулятор версия 1.6")
r = str("Решение = ")
what = input("""Что сделать? (+, -, *, /, возвести в степень (^), делить по модулю (%)
вычисление корня степени = второму числу из первого числа (//), +-a, +-b
вычисление логарифма из первого числа по основанию второго числа(/^)
вычислить синус первого числа (вводить градусы) (sin1)
вычислить косинус первого числа (вводить градусы) (cos1)
вычислить тангенс первого числа (вводить градусы) (tg1)
вычислить котангенс первого числа (вводить градусы) (сtg1)) = """)
if what == "sin1" or what == "cos1" or what == "tg1" or what == "ctg1":
    a = float(input('введите первое число = '))
    b = 0
else:
    a = float(input('введите первое число = '))
    b = float(input("введите второе число = ")) 
if what == "+-a" or what == "+-b":
    if what == "+-a":
        a -= a*2
    elif what == "+-b":
        b -= b*2
    what = input("""Что сделать? (+, -, *, /, возвести в степень (^), делить по модулю (%)
вычисление корня степени = второму числу из первого числа (//)
вычисление логарифма из первого числа по основанию второго числа(/^)
вычислить синус первого числа (вводить градусы) (sin1)
вычислить косинус первого числа (вводить градусы) (cos1)
вычислить тангенс первого числа (вводить градусы) (tg1)
вычислить котангенс первого числа (вводить градусы) (сtg1)) = """)
    import secondcalc
elif what == "+" or what == "-" or what == "*" or what == "/" or what == "^" or what == "%" or what == "//" or what == "/^" or what == "sin1" or what == "cos1" or what == "tg1" or what == "ctg1":
    import secondcalc
else:
    res = ("IDK")
    if res == "IDK":
        res = res
    else:
        res = float('{:.15f}'.format(res))
input(r + str(res))
```

secondcalc.py

```
import math
from maincalc import what, a, b
if what == "+":
    res = (a + b)
elif what == "-":
    res = (a - b)
elif what == "*":
    res = (a * b)
elif what == "/":
    res = (a / b)
elif what == "^":
    res = (a ** b)
elif what == "%":
    res = (a % b)
elif what == "//":
    res = (a ** (1 / b))
elif what == "/^":
    res = (math.log(a, b))
elif what == "sin1":
    res = (math.sin(math.radians(a)))
elif what == "cos1":
    res = (math.cos(math.radians(a)))
elif what == "tg1":
    res = (math.tan(math.radians(a)))
elif what == "ctg1":
    res = (math.cos(math.radians(a)) / math.sin(math.radians(a)))
else:
    res = ("IDK")
import maincalc
```

Comment: Просто импортировать файл. При импорте исполнится весь его код. Но сделать это можно однократно.

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте создал отдельную функцию и просто использовал бы её там, где нужно.

Comment: Да, но я не знаю как сделать это т.к. только начал изучать питон

Comment: Спасибо @nomnoms12